# Run a task once after x days with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing an application in which you have `Offers` and `Counter-offers`. When I create a offer, I want to schedule a task to run 5 days after to check if it has any counteroffer. If it doesn't have any counteroffer, the offer status will set to expired.

I have read about the `@Scheduled` annotation, but it only runs a task every x days, but I want to one run a task only after a offer is created and only once for each new offer. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am late and not a spring expert but I have a solution for this create a scheduled component using annotation is easier

```
class OfferClass {
    public Date creationDate;
    // .... user related info
}

@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class OfferManager {
    private static final long interval_milliSeconds = 60*60*1000; // scheduled to run once every hour
    public List<OfferClass> offersList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = interval_milliSeconds)
    public void timeout() {
        Date now = new Date(); // current timestamp
        for (OfferClass offer:this.offersList) {
            // check if 5 days are spent
            if (now.getTime() - offer.date.getTime() > 5 days) {
               // Do your action and remove the offer from the offersList
               this.offersList.remove(offer)
            }
        }
    }

}

// Usage
void main() {
    // Add an offer to the array
    offerClass newOffer = new offerClass();
    newOffer.creationDate = new Date() // set start date
    // Add offer to offer manager and wait for magic
    OfferManager.offersList.add(newOffer)
}
```

I know is not the best answer and optimised but I'm an iOS dev not spring a quick improvment will be to dig into "@Scheduled(fixedRate=...)" annotation maybe use of other option such as cron or fixeDelay could fdo better job Good luck

Comment: This is probably the best answer that OP will get on this topic - running *exactly* after X amount of time for each created objects will require something like spawning an individual Thread for each object, whereas the logic in this answer is extensible to any number of objects and time frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you the straight answer, rather you can go towards using Spring Task Scheduler.

Spring 3.0 introduces a TaskScheduler for scheduling tasks. It’s part of the Spring-Core, no need to declare an extra dependency.

Create cron job like following Spring configuration

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
   <task:scheduled ref="offerScheduler" method="processOffer" cron="0 1 * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Make sure you have class called "OfferSchedueled" and it has "processOffer" method to perform your logic to change offer status everyday at 1 AM.

```
@Component
public class OfferSchedueled {

 public void processOffer(){
   //Get all non expired offers into a list or any collection
   //Loop through each of them
  //Check it's time span between created date and today is 5 days
  //if so and it doesn't have any counter offers, then mark that as expired
 }

}
```

For more reading:

http://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/07/spring-batch-job-executing-scheduled.html
http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/

Comment: Hi, using a cron job you can run tasks periodically, but you can't run a task after x days starting at irregular point in time.

Comment: What you said is absolutely correct, but what I am trying to say is run the cron task periodically and write your logic in such as way that it will process offers in whatever the way you wanted. (I have written high level psuedo code in the above answer)

Comment: Yes, that's an approximate answer to the solution, but it's not what I want, because if you use a cron job, the task can be executed after 5 days and 23 hours for example. I want to execute a task only 5 days after an `Offer` is create.